# How to move a metastore to a new Storage Account in Databricks Unity Catalog?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I would like to change the Metastore location in Databricks Account Console. I have one metastore created that is in an undesired container/storage account. I could see that it's not possible to edit a metastore that is already created. I could also see that it's not possible to create a second metastore in the same Azure region. Well, does anyone know how to move this metastore to another storage account? I was wondering, if I simply move the container to a new Account via Az Copy and then delete and recreate the metatore in the new location, will it work?

[image]

Comment: Using azcopy to lift and shift the data to another container *may* not work in some cases where metadata contains *absolute paths* to cloud files in the same storage container. Also, even if you are able to copy the data over safely, recreating the Metastore will lose the existing definitions for access control lists, catalogs, schemas, tables, volumes, models, functions, etc.